# Using jUddi v3 from .net and java

Tags: java, .net, web-services, uddi, juddi

I have built a Web Service in .NET. I have some apps that need to find and consume it, so I am using jUddi v3. I know that this version lets you use the publish, inquiry and security services as web services, but I have also heard that there are some APIs that let you interact with it from .NET and Java (Uddi SDK and Uddi4J), and that is what I need.

I am looking for any tutorial or some tips that could help me to publish my .NET web service from .NET applications and discover and use it from .NET and Java applications.

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Apache jUDDI project has a .NET client and examples that should help you out.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/juddi-client.net/

https://github.com/UDDI/juddi/wiki/devjUDDIClientforNET

https://github.com/UDDI/juddi/wiki/devSimplePublishingUsingthejUDDIAPI